# Distribute the Order's freight cost value on order's items according to item's share from the overall order Total

Tags: vba, ms-access

[Please Open this image, It will Clarify my Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9tC.jpg)
I have a database with tables : orders, order_details, Products and so on.
each order has a Total, freight_cost and so on with other fields.
Each order_details have a subtotal and of course with other fields.
I want to calculate the share of freight value for each item in the order from the over all total of that order's freight_cost. Please, open the image in beginning of my question to clarify clearly what I want to do.

Comment: Please , open the attached image , it will clarify my question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible with aggregate query joined to data table or use domain aggregate functions. Easiest might actually be to do in a report using Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calcs. If you want to save the calcs then likely need VBA custom function.  When you have an attempt with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly maybe this will help.  The easiest approach is to create a query that extends the order_details table to include the calculated variable itemfreightcost[image: .]

This gives you a virtual table on which you can base your form or report:

[image]

note 1: I included quantity in the order-details table and item freight calculations as it seemed natural.

note 2: the expression for itemfreightcost is itemfreightcost: [order_details]![subtotal]*[order_details]![ItemQuantity]/[Orders]![Freight_Cost] .  In other words item price * quantity divided by total freight cost.

note 3: you can also base your report on order and order details and add the itemfreightcost calculated variable directly to the details section of the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to which you pass an array of the quantities and the total cost, and an array holding the detailed cost is returned:

```
' Rounds a series of numbers so the sum of these matches the
' rounded sum of the unrounded values.
' Further, if a requested total is passed, the rounded values
' will be scaled, so the sum of these matches the rounded total.
' In cases where the sum of the rounded values doesn't match
' the rounded total, the rounded values will be adjusted where
' the applied error will be the relatively smallest.
'
' The series of values to round must be passed as an array.
' The data type can be any numeric data type, and values can have
' any value.
' Internally, the function uses Decimal to achieve the highest
' precision and Double when the values exceed the range of Decimal.
'
' The result is an array holding the rounded values, as well as
' (by reference) the rounded total.
'
' If non-numeric values are passed, an error is raised.
'
' Requires:
'   RoundMid
'
' 2018-03-26. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundSum( _
    ByVal Values As Variant, _
    Optional ByRef Total As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Long) _
    As Variant

    Dim SortedItems()   As Long
    Dim RoundedValues   As Variant
    Dim SortingValues   As Variant

    Dim Sum             As Variant
    Dim Value           As Variant
    Dim RoundedSum      As Variant
    Dim RoundedTotal    As Variant
    Dim PlusSum         As Variant
    Dim MinusSum        As Variant
    Dim RoundedPlusSum  As Variant
    Dim RoundedMinusSum As Variant

    Dim ErrorNumber     As Long
    Dim Item            As Long
    Dim Sign            As Variant
    Dim Ratio           As Variant
    Dim Difference      As Variant
    Dim Delta           As Variant
    Dim SortValue       As Variant

    ' Raise error if an array is not passed.
    Item = UBound(Values)

    ' Ignore errors while summing the values.
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' Try to sum the passed values as a Decimal.
        Sum = CDec(0)
        For Item = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
            If IsNumeric(Values(Item)) Then
                Sum = Sum + CDec(Values(Item))
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Values exceed range of Decimal.
                    ' Exit loop and try using Double.
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Try to sum the passed values as a Double.
        Err.Clear
        Sum = CDbl(0)
        For Item = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
            If IsNumeric(Values(Item)) Then
                Sum = Sum + CDbl(Values(Item))
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Values exceed range of Double.
                    ' Exit loop and raise error.
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ' Collect the error number as "On Error Goto 0" will clear it.
    ErrorNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ErrorNumber <> 0 Then
        ' Extreme values. Give up.
        Error.Raise ErrorNumber
    End If

    ' Correct a missing or invalid parameter value for Total.
    If Not IsNumeric(Total) Then
        Total = 0
    End If
    If Total = 0 Then
        RoundedTotal = 0
    Else
        ' Round Total to an appropriate data type.
        ' Set data type of RoundedTotal to match Sum.
        Select Case VarType(Sum)
            Case vbSingle, vbDouble
                Value = CDbl(Total)
            Case Else
                Value = CDec(Total)
        End Select
        RoundedTotal = RoundMid(Value, NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
    End If

    ' Calculate scaling factor and sign.
    If Sum = 0 Or RoundedTotal = 0 Then
        ' Cannot scale a value of zero.
        Sign = 1
        Ratio = 1
    Else
        Sign = Sgn(Sum) * Sgn(RoundedTotal)
        ' Ignore error and convert to Double if total exceeds the range of Decimal.
        On Error Resume Next
        Ratio = Abs(RoundedTotal / Sum)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            RoundedTotal = CDbl(RoundedTotal)
            Ratio = Abs(RoundedTotal / Sum)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    ' Create array to hold the rounded values.
    RoundedValues = Values
    ' Scale and round the values and sum the rounded values.
    ' Variables will get the data type of RoundedValues.
    ' Ignore error and convert to Double if total exceeds the range of Decimal.
    On Error Resume Next
    For Item = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
        RoundedValues(Item) = RoundMid(Values(Item) * Ratio, NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
        If RoundedValues(Item) > 0 Then
            PlusSum = PlusSum + Values(Item)
            RoundedPlusSum = RoundedPlusSum + RoundedValues(Item)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                RoundedPlusSum = CDbl(RoundedPlusSum) + CDbl(RoundedValues(Item))
            End If
        Else
            MinusSum = MinusSum + Values(Item)
            RoundedMinusSum = RoundedMinusSum + RoundedValues(Item)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                RoundedMinusSum = CDbl(RoundedMinusSum) + CDbl(RoundedValues(Item))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    RoundedSum = RoundedPlusSum + RoundedMinusSum
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        RoundedPlusSum = CDbl(RoundedPlusSum)
        RoundedMinusSum = CDbl(RoundedMinusSum)
        RoundedSum = RoundedPlusSum + RoundedMinusSum
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If RoundedTotal = 0 Then
        ' No total is requested.
        ' Use as total the rounded sum of the passed unrounded values.
        RoundedTotal = RoundMid(Sum, NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
    End If

    ' Check if a correction of the rounded values is needed.
    If (RoundedPlusSum + RoundedMinusSum = 0) And (RoundedTotal = 0) Then
        ' All items are rounded to zero. Nothing to do.
        ' Return zero.
    ElseIf RoundedSum = RoundedTotal Then
        ' Match. Nothing more to do.
    ElseIf RoundedSum = Sign * RoundedTotal Then
        ' Match, except that values shall be reversely signed.
        ' Will be done later before exit.
    Else
        ' Correction is needed.
        ' Redim array to hold the sorting of the rounded values.
        ReDim SortedItems(LBound(Values) To UBound(Values))
        ' Fill array with default sorting.
        For Item = LBound(SortedItems) To UBound(SortedItems)
            SortedItems(Item) = Item
        Next

        ' Create array to hold the values to sort.
        SortingValues = RoundedValues
        ' Fill the array after the relative rounding error and - for items with equal rounding error - the
        ' size of the value of items.
        For Item = LBound(SortedItems) To UBound(SortedItems)
            If Values(SortedItems(Item)) = 0 Then
                ' Zero value.
                SortValue = 0
            ElseIf RoundedPlusSum + RoundedMinusSum = 0 Then
                ' Values have been rounded to zero.
                ' Use original values.
                SortValue = Values(SortedItems(Item))
            ElseIf VarType(Values(SortedItems(Item))) = vbDouble Then
                ' Calculate relative rounding error.
                ' Value is exceeding Decimal. Use Double.
                SortValue = (Values(SortedItems(Item)) * Ratio - CDbl(RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item)))) * (Values(SortedItems(Item)) / Sum)
            Else
                ' Calculate relative rounding error using Decimal.
                SortValue = (Values(SortedItems(Item)) * Ratio - RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item))) * (Values(SortedItems(Item)) / Sum)
            End If
            ' Sort on the absolute value.
            SortingValues(Item) = Abs(SortValue)
        Next

        ' Sort the array after the relative rounding error and - for items with equal rounding error - the
        ' size of the value of items.
        QuickSortIndex SortedItems, SortingValues

        ' Distribute a difference between the rounded sum and the requested total.
        If RoundedPlusSum + RoundedMinusSum = 0 Then
            ' All rounded values are zero.
            ' Set Difference to the rounded total.
            Difference = RoundedTotal
        Else
            Difference = Sgn(RoundedSum) * (Abs(RoundedTotal) - Abs(RoundedSum))
        End If
        ' If Difference is positive, some values must be rounded up.
        ' If Difference is negative, some values must be rounded down.
        ' Calculate Delta, the value to increment/decrement by.
        Delta = Sgn(Difference) * 10 ^ -NumDigitsAfterDecimal

        ' Loop the rounded values and increment/decrement by Delta until Difference is zero.
        For Item = UBound(SortedItems) To LBound(SortedItems) Step -1
            ' If values should be incremented, ignore values rounded up.
            ' If values should be decremented, ignore values rounded down.
            If Sgn(Difference) = Sgn(Values(SortedItems(Item)) * Ratio - RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item))) Then
                ' Adjust this item.
                RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item)) = RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item)) + Delta
                If Item > LBound(SortedItems) Then
                    ' Check if the next item holds the exact reverse value.
                    If Values(SortedItems(Item)) = -Values(SortedItems(Item - 1)) Then
                        ' Adjust the next item as well to avoid uneven incrementing.
                        Item = Item - 1
                        RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item)) = RoundedValues(SortedItems(Item)) - Delta
                        Difference = Difference + Delta
                    End If
                End If
                Difference = Difference - Delta
            End If
            If Difference = 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If Sign = -1 Then
        ' The values shall be reversely signed.
        For Item = LBound(RoundedValues) To UBound(RoundedValues)
            RoundedValues(Item) = -RoundedValues(Item)
        Next
    End If

    ' Return the rounded total.
    Total = RoundedTotal
    ' Return the array holding the rounded values.
    RoundSum = RoundedValues

End Function
```

The full code is on **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

For a detailed walk-through of the code, study my article:

[Round elements of a sum to match a total](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31683/Round-elements-of-a-sum-to-match-a-total.html)

A login isn't required. Just locate the link to "Read the full article" or similar.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. Very helpful indeed.